# Gradient Backgrounds in internet explorer version <=8

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

I need to have gradient backgrounds on my website for internet explorer. I know there is some kind of proprietry way of doing this:

```
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient(startColorStr='#20799d', EndColorStr='#5cb9df');
```

But this doesn't grok with `border-radius` (supported by IE8, at least), which my site uses all over the place.

How should I solve this? (Other than just not having gradient backgrounds on old versions of IE, I mean.)

Comment: `border-radius` isn't supported by IE8. They add support only in IE9

Comment: @antyrat is correct: http://caniuse.com/#search=border-radius

Comment: Well, on my site it's working for IE8, but not IE7. Possible due to some other hack library I applied in the past?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a great library called [CSS3PIE](http://css3pie.com/), which adds support to IE 6-7-8-9 for many of the CSS3 stuff you seem to be interested in.

I'm using it a lot, and it's never let me down (although it does have its quirks).

Comment: Brilliant! That looks perfect. Are there any caveats, or does it just work?

Comment: More here: https://github.com/lojjic/PIE/issues  It's not a perfect solution, but it is the closest thing to it that exists. I **highly** recommend PIE, but performance is sometimes slow and there are definitely some issues once you really get going with it.